# Keyboard layout not really changing after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 17 to 18.04. I regularly use 2 keyboards, but even if I change the keyboard layout from the Keyboard settings config window (no extras, the default one), the keyboard layout does not change. I mean, I can change the current layout, I can see the thumbnail changing in the taskbar, but such change does not affect the keyboard, which is always working with the same layout.

The only way I managed to change the layout is executing:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

But it takes too long to generate the configs and change the layout (being used to just a click).

The output of "cat /etc/default/keyboard" is:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="asus_laptop"
XKBLAYOUT="es"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

And the output of "gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options" is:

```
@as []
```

Do you know what can I do to get back the missing functionality? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of these two commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Done @GunnarHjalmarsson :)

Comment: Ok, no explanation there. Did you see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html)?